# Make <p> tag remaining width of div with a link (which has an icon as a background) to the right of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html:

```
<div id="cobcContainer" class='floatLeft' style="width: 50%">
    <p id="containerText">Random long text here. This text takes up two lines when it is inside it's container div (inside cobcContainer).</p>
    <a class="square bookIcon" href="/"></a>
</div>
```

In the CSS (there is a style.css which I do not have access to) the

```
<a class="square bookIcon" href="/"></a>
```

has a background image and the width of it is 100px.

There is not any other CSS in this. When I view the webpage, the container is 50% and the text appears first and then the link / icon appears below it. How do I make the link / icon appear to the right of the text (make the text aligned to the left of the icon / link)? I need this to be a responsive design so I am trying to use percentages here (other than the link / icon which has a fixed width of 100px).

JQuery / JS can be used.

Note: I am not allowed to use

```
<table>
```

tags nor

```
display: table-cell
```

(these rules were set by the corporation).

Comment: `p {
    float:left;
}`?

Answer (score 1):

p is a block level element, so any element after it will be below it. and as you have defined 100px width for a tag,

1) you can do this,

```
#containerText{
display:inline-block;
}
```

and define some width to it.

2) Or simply put

`.square  { float:left; }`

This will float to the left and a tag will just come beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/63/

You can use

```
#containerText {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And in tandem (not necessary) to push the link to the right side of the div:

```
.bookIcon {
    float:right;
}
```

If float:right isnt used, then the link will be on the right, right next to the text

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of p tag using `calc` and add a `float: left` to the anchor tag.

```
a.square {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
}
p {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/fnvbo5hr/1/)